# Smaller or equal comparison syntax error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

My UDF is comparing if time difference between two columns is within 5 days limit. If == operator is used, expression compiles properly, but <= (or `lt`) fails with type mismatch error. Code:

```
val isExpiration : (Column, Column, Column) =>
Column = (BCED, termEnd, agrEnd) =>
{
   if(abs(datediff(if(termEnd == null) {agrEnd} else {termEnd}, BCED)) lt 6)
      {lit(0)}
else
      {lit(1)}
}
```

Error:

```
notebook:3: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Boolean
    if(abs(datediff(if(termEnd == null) {agrEnd} else {termEnd}, BCED)) lt 6) {lit(0)}...
                                                                        ^
```

I must be missing something obvious - can anyone advice how to test if **Column** value is smaller or equal to a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have mixed `udf` and Spark functions, you need to use only one of them. When possible it's always preferable *not* to use and `udf` since those can not be optimized (and are thus generally slower). Without `udf` it could be done as follows:

```
df.withColumn("end", when($"termEnd".isNull, $"agrEnd").otherwise($"termEnd"))
  .withColumn("expired", when(abs(datediff($"end", $"BCED")) lt 6, 0).otherwise(1))
```

I introduced a temporary column to make the code a bit more readable.

---

Using an `udf` it could, for example, be done as follows:

```
val isExpired = udf((a: Date, b: Date) => {
  if ((math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) < 6) { 
    0
  } else { 
    1
  }
})

df.withColumn("end", when($"termEnd".isNull, $"agrEnd").otherwise($"termEnd"))
  .withColumn("expired", isExpired($"end", $"BCED"))
```

Here, I again made use of a temporary column but this logic could be moved into the `udf` if preferred.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `abs(col).lt(6)` returns an object of type `Column` and `if` expects the condition to be evaluated to `true` or `false` which is a Scala `Boolean` type.

Plus, UDF doesn't work on `Column` Data Type, it works with Scala Objects (`Int`, `String`, `Boolean` etc)

Since all you're doing is using Spark SQL functions, you can rewrite your *UDF* like this:

```
val isExpiration = (
    when(
        abs(datediff(coalesce($"termEnd", $"agrEnd") , $"BCED")) <= 6, lit(0)
    ).otherwise(lit(1))
)
```

And, the usage would be:

```
df.show
//+----------+----------+----------+
//|      BCED|   termEnd|    agrEnd|
//+----------+----------+----------+
//|2018-06-10|2018-06-25|2018-06-25|
//|2018-06-10|      null|2018-06-15|
//+----------+----------+----------+


df.withColumn("x", isExpiration).show
//+----------+----------+----------+---+
//|      BCED|   termEnd|    agrEnd|  x|
//+----------+----------+----------+---+
//|2018-06-10|2018-06-25|2018-06-25|  1|
//|2018-06-10|      null|2018-06-15|  0|
//+----------+----------+----------+---+
```